# Why are my images and captions not getting styled inside a flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the images on this page have a rounded edge and I've applied the appropriate CSS styling using combinator selectors. But somehow they are not getting applied? Same for the captions.

```css
.pagecontents{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #A4B3B6
}

.pagecontents figure img{
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 40px 10px 20px 10px
}

.pagecontents figure figcaption{
    font-family: Arial
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagecontents">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91bbRIClz+L.jpg" alt="Cover of Norwegian Wood" height="300">
        <figcaption>
            Norwegian Wood <br>
            Author: Haruki Murakami
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XSN3hA5gL.jpg" alt="Cover of Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" height="300">
        <figcaption>
            Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy <br>
            Author: Douglas Adams
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+f5? CSS is cached.

Comment: You've missed semicolon in CSS after `font-family: Arial`

Comment: Tried both of the above, still not rendering the images and captions as I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed semicolon in CSS after `font-family: Arial`
`border-radius` is not visible because of `padding` - [look here to see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWfdx.png)
(I've added `background-color` to `<img>`)
Probably, `padding` is not the best choice for `<img>`. Maybe, you should use `margin`?

```css
.pagecontents{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #A4B3B6
}

.pagecontents figure img{
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 40px 10px 20px 10px; /* Changed padding to margin, added semicolon */
}

.pagecontents figure figcaption{
    font-family: Arial; /* Added semicolon */
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagecontents">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91bbRIClz+L.jpg" alt="Cover of Norwegian Wood" height="300">
        <figcaption>
            Norwegian Wood <br>
            Author: Haruki Murakami
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XSN3hA5gL.jpg" alt="Cover of Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" height="300">
        <figcaption>
            Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy <br>
            Author: Douglas Adams
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pagecontents figure img {
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Add some paddings for .pagecontents figure figcaption{}